# Packaging a modified Qt class

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, qml, packaging

Heads up, this is going to be confusing:

I customized 9 files from Qt5.2: qquicktextdocument.cpp qquicktextdocument.h qquicktextedit.cpp qquicktextedit_p.h qquicktextedit_p_p.h qquicktextnode.cpp qquicktextnodeengine.cpp qquicktextnodeengine_p.h qquicktextnode_p.h

Each file is simply prefixed with a letter and still inside /qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/. I am 100% happy with the modifications I made being put under GPL etc. I somewhat want my end application (discussed below) to be Apache or MIT, but, I'm flexible.

My modifications work fine. When I modify a few additional files I am able to compile them along with the rest of Qt (at the same time, using the same make command). But these modifications are going into another Qt application that I am making which I want other people to be able to use, and requiring general consumers to have a custom compiled version of Qt would be obviously absurd.

I want to package/compile/do something, that will enable me to include the modifications in my final project as a shared library, or something.

As a web developer writing C++ and Qt, I am very confused about linking shared libraries, header files, etc.

To recap, I modified Qt 5.2 and made a custom compilation of it for an application I am building, and I want people to be able to run that application without having to have a custom compilation of Qt. I need a way to decouple my Qt modifications from Qt.

I realize this might be a big topic, I'm not expecting a step by step guide, just some general guidance. So far I have tried compiling my modified files as a library, then including that library in my actual project, but I am getting undefined references and missing files all over the place. (I don't know if I did anything right)

I am also currently looking at subclassing the classes I want but I'm unsure about this. It might require copy pasting some code, which could have licensing issues?

end goal: be able to have a wavy underline (in qml) for incorrectly spelt words.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents.

1. If your changes can be useful (in general) to other people you can try to push them to upstream via [codereview](http://codereview.qt-project.org/).
2. If you want your application to run only in windows everything become obvious: in windows it is normal to provide your application with shared libraries (to avoid DLL HELL). Btw, have you heard about static linking?
3. Qt has some `plugin` mechanism. You can compile your code into shared object (dynamic library) and install it with your application. For example, QML FolderListModel do this. You can look at code in `$qt5_src/qtdeclarative/src/imports/folderlistmodel`.